# how to load child1.qml page on to main.qml page calling from another_child.qml page

Tags: qt, qml

**In my MyHeader.qml cannot load the MyChild2.qml.** How to load child qml page on to mmain.qml page calling from another child qml page as shown below.

- TestProject Folder

  - qml Folder

    - Main.qml
    - MyChild1.qml
    - mainui Folder

      - MyHeader.qml
      - MyChild2.qml

---

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import "."

// Main.qml

ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootApp

    Loader {
        id: loaderPage
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

    MyChild1 {
    }
}


// MyChild1.qml
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import "."

Page {
    id: myItem1
    anchors.fill: parent

    MyHeader {
        anchors.top: parent.top
    }
}


// MyChild2.qml
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import "."

Page {
    id: myItem2
    anchors.fill: parent

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#000000"
    }

}



// MyHeader.qml
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import "."

    Rectangle {
        id: myHeader
        width: parent.width
        height: dp(30)
        color: "lightblue"

        Text {
            id: loadQML
            text: "Load QML"
            color: "#000000"
            font.pixelSize: dp(20)

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    myItem1.visible = false
                    loaderPage.source = "MyChild2.qml"
                    loaderPage.Top
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

---

Using the Loader and Connection I am getting Cannot assign to non-existent property "onPageChanged"

```
import QtQuick 2.10

import "mainui"

ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootApp

    signal pageChanged(int page);

    Loader {
        id:rootLoader
        anchors.fill: parent
        source: "mainui/Page1.qml"

        Connections {
            target: rootLoader.item
            onPageChanged: {
                switch(page)
                {
                    case 1: rootLoader.source = "mainui/Page1.qml"; break;
                    case 2: rootLoader.source = "mainui/Page2.qml"; break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

} // APP
```

Comment: Please post all the appropriate code. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article too.

Comment: @folibis I update my question.

Answer (score 1):

Due to scope limitation of `Loader` you cannot access items outside it. But you can *notify* the `Loader` to do some action. In the example below there are 2 components define a signal. The `Loader` connects this signal to a handler:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    id: win
    width: 400
    height: 400
    title: "Test"
    visible: true

    Component {
        id:  page1
        Rectangle {
            signal pageChanged(int page);
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "orange"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "PAGE 1\nClick to change"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    pageChanged(2);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id:  page2
        Rectangle {
            signal pageChanged(int page);
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "lightblue"
            Text {
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                text: "PAGE 2\nClick to change"
                horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            }
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: {
                    pageChanged(1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Loader {
        id: loader
        anchors.fill: parent
        sourceComponent: page1
        Connections {
            target: loader.item
            onPageChanged: {
                switch(page)
                {
                    case 1: loader.sourceComponent = page1; break;
                    case 2: loader.sourceComponent = page2; break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for info. To understand better I have to ask again. Your first component (id: page1) you create a rectangle. In here I need to load my own qml (mainui/MyChild2.qml). how do I do that?

Comment: The component here is for example only. You could use qml file (and Loader.source) instead.

Comment: thanks. my problem is that I am having difficulty to combine your info so I can load nested qml. Example I can load the nested qml to top of main.qml. But when I click exit button on nested qml page the main.qml become empty.

Comment: I update my question. I try to implement as what you post. But I am getting an error on onPageChanged handler. any advice?